# How do I remove a line containing word in multiple files?

Tags: bash, sed, find

I want to remove a line that contains `<premiered>` in *.nfo files including subdirectories.

This is the command that I use

```
find . -type f -name '*.nfo' -exec sh -c '
  file="$0"
  echo "$file"
  sed -i -e '/<premiered>/d' "&file"
  read line </dev/tty
' {} ';'
```

Unfortunately, all i get is

```
-bash: premiered: No such file or directory
```

Whats the problem and how can i fix that?

Comment: The issue is that single quotes don't nest, so `<premiered` is exposed to the shell (and is interpreted as a redirection). Why do you think it necessary to wrap the `sed` command in a `sh -c`?

Comment: If single quote dont nest, what command should I use? I wrap sed because this find . -name "*.nfo" -type f | xargs sed -i -e '/<premiered>/d' doesnt work.

Comment: I don't know why `xargs` wouldn't work, but it should be possible to run sed directly via -exec i.e. `find . -type f -name '*.nfo' -exec sed -i -e '/<premiered>/d' {} \;`

Comment: Thanks. That works. Why dont you answer and ill mark it as answer.

Comment: OK thanks - done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that quotes don't nest, so that you are actually *closing* quotes before `/<premiered>/d` and opening them again after. That means that `<premiered>` is exposed to the invoking shell, where the `<` and `>` are interpreted as redirection operators.

There's really no need to wrap the sed command in a shell command - you can run it directly as the argument to the `find ... -exec`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.nfo' -exec sed -i -e '/<premiered>/d' {} \;
```

If you want to echo the filename as well, add a separate `-print`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.nfo' -print -exec sed -i -e '/<premiered>/d' {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks. I was gonna ask how can i see the progress. -print answered it nicely.

Comment: Note that `sed -i` (where supported) can process more than one file per invocation. Using `+` instead of `\;` would make it more efficient (and also make `find` return a non-zero exit status if any of the `sed` invocations fail).